# Why did I lose my reputation without any down votes

Tags: support, reputation

I've seen this many times, but did not get why this is happening.
Here first I had seen a screen like below where my score is 811
[image]

I refreshed the page and the screen shows 809:

[image]

I've looked on my reputation dashboard, but nothing there seems to be down voted.

How can I find out on which post this action was taken?

Comment: Most likely a post you edited was deleted so you lost the +2 for editing it.  That removes it from the list so you just "lose" 2 rep.

Comment: _"How can I find where"_ There's the `Reputation` in your user profile (Activity) where you can see the details.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not for removed suggested edits, those vanish without leaving a trace, as if the edit never happened..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ *There's the Reputation in your user profile (Activity) where you can see the details* I can't see over there

Comment: @Floern I've just noticed that after I wrote the comment and inspected the OP's profile.

Comment: @NathanOliver's correct. The -2 you got from an edit last week was effectively cancelled out when the OP deleted it a few hours ago. I wouldn't worry about it.